# Solving the Exact DE: $x\dfrac{dy}{dx}=2xe^x-y+6x^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

Solving the Exact DE: $$x\dfrac{dy}{dx}=2xe^x-y+6x^2$$

I first re-wrote the ecuation, in order to have $M(x, y)$ and $N(x,y)$:

$$(2xe^x-y+6x^2)dx-x dy$$

And, by having the partial derivative:
$$\dfrac{\partial M(x, y)}{\partial y}=\dfrac{\partial (2xe^x-y+6x^2)}{\partial y}=-1$$
$$\dfrac{\partial N(x, y)}{\partial x}=\dfrac{\partial (-x)}{\partial x}=-1$$

So te equation is EXACT

Then, if $f$ exist:
$$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}=M(x, y)$$
so
$$f(x, y)=\int (2xe^x-y+6x^2)dx+g(y)=2xe^x-2e^x-yx+2x^3+g(y)$$
Derivating respect $y$:
$$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}=N(x, y)$$
$$-x+q(y)=-x \implies g´(x)=0 \implies g(x)=c$$

where $c$ is constant.

So, the general solution is:

$$f(x, y)=2xe^x-2e^x-yx+2x^3+c=c$$

Can someone tell me if this is well done?

Comment: Why don't you double check using, e.g., Wolfram, by plugging-in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your result is fine but you may also proceed as below to check.

Reduce the equation to the form $\frac{dy}{dx}+P(x)y=Q(x)$ where $P(x)=\frac{1}{x}$, $Q(x)=2e^x+6x$ Then find the Integrating factor(I.F.) which is $e^{\int P(x)dx}=x$ here. Then you have the solution as $$y\cdot x=\int
x(2e^x+6x)dx +c\Rightarrow y=2(xe^x-e^x+2x^3)/x+c/x$$